# Prevent Sheets From Opening When Cycling Through

Tags: vba, excel

I have a program where information is entered on one sheet and a new sheet is created for each row that has entered information. As a result, 1 to 152 sheets can possibly be created and each of these sheets has formatting, calculations, and other things occuring on them from VBA. However, to make it happen faster, if it is even possible, I would like to stop Excel from opening these sheets each time they are created and simply jump to the end. Like I said, I'm not sure if this is possible, but it would be nice. I haven't yet found anything relating to the subject found on Google and I'm not sure how I would go about it myself. I appreciate any help.

Comment: You question is unclear to me, but you can turn off the `ScreenUpdating` before your code runs to prevent the screen from flashing, and each sheet being visible, and activated, as it is inserted.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` at the top of your code. This will prevent the screen from flashing as each sheet gets created and activated.